# Google Analytics: Events sent, but not showing up in reports

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am sending events to google analytics via ga() function:

```js
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'event',
  'eventCategory': 'Article',
  'eventAction': 'Purchase',
  'eventLabel': window.location.href.split('?')[0],
  'eventValue': r.data.price,
  'useBeacon': true,
  'hitCallback': function() {
    googleSent = true;
  }
});
```

The callback get's executed properly, the chrome analytics debuger shows that the events are being sent to google analytics. But nothing is showing up – neither in the realtime reports nor in the regular reports.

Any ideas what can cause this particular problem?

Comment: It could just be an issue on Google's side with RT reports. I'm currently not seeing any activity either (and I'm not filtering my own visits). Standard reports won't show data from anywhere between 6-48 hours as it needs to be processed still in the backend.

Comment: @nyuen The first events were sent more than 48 hours back, but still they're not showing up in any reports. Additionally the events were sent from different IP addresses.

Comment: can you post the full tracking code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone, today i could figure out what the real issue behind that behavior was:

eventValue was a float, but it has to be an integer, so it wasn't count on the analytics servers. 
That's all.

Comment: Great, somebody including me thought the Value property could be a number or string and then the event would not be recorded on GA. :)