# Google Analytics Event not showing up

Tags: google-analytics

I have an AMP page where I've included Google Tag Manager (GTM). Now I've created a "universal click" tag which is supposed to log every click into Google Analytics (GA).

[image: google tag manager setup: category, action, label, value]

It looks fine in the dev console:

[image: dev console returns 200]

A request is sent to the URL: https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=a0&ds=AMP&aip=true&_s=3&dt=TypeScript%20MEAN&sr=1440x900&_utmht=1502735532566&cid=amp-2_4H1svvoL5wMZhnu8K97QEZkF1WNTydh_RkN3aMjHLPZwYUx22pjPPFLWsyTwe4&tid=UA-70730318-4&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tsmean.com%2F&dr=&sd=24&ul=en-gb&de=UTF-8&jid=&t=event&ec=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tsmean.com%2F&ea=click&el=9&ev=&a=2321&z=0.08240769669002734

It seems to contain all the important query parameters:

- ec=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tsmean.com%2F&ea=click&el=9
- ea=click
- el=9
- ev is empty in this case but to my understanding a value is not required where as the other three are?

Yet in Google Analytics Real Time Events, only the "Scroll-Events" I've also confiugred show up and nothing is seen of any click events:

[image: google analytics real time not logging event]

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 9):

You can debug adding the prefix /debug to the URL. Example :

https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&_v=a0&ds=AMP&aip=true&_s=3&dt=TypeScript%20MEAN&sr=1440x900&_utmht=1502735532566&cid=amp-2_4H1svvoL5wMZhnu8K97QEZkF1WNTydh_RkN3aMjHLPZwYUx22pjPPFLWsyTwe4&tid=UA-70730318-4&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tsmean.com%2F&dr=&sd=24&ul=en-gb&de=UTF-8&jid=&t=event&ec=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tsmean.com%2F&ea=click&el=9&ev=&a=2321&z=0.08240769669002734

This is the message of error of that hit, it is not valid! 
[image]
So removing the EV parameter on you tag should work it perfect (this is the tested preview on my account)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out thanks to [Google Analytics: Events sent, but not showing up in reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174225/google-analytics-events-sent-but-not-showing-up-in-reports)

I assumed an **event value** "ev=" is okay because I thought it's the same as just not sending an event value. This is not the case. "ev=" is not accepted by GA. **You either have to leave away the value completely (i.e. not even an empty query parameter may be sent) or otherwise you have to provide a non-negative integer.**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the now "old" implementation of analytics.js on a web page, and I added a new gtags.js implementation and it "worked" but didn't show up on my new site to monitor. The events were sent to the old implementation.